# Partial surface area of right trapezoid.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to get a formula for $x_2$ coordinate of right trapezoid ABCD, which surface area equals $s$, given $(x_0, y_o)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$.

[image]

I arrived to this equation:
$$\frac a2x_2^2 + (y_0-ax_0)x_2 - y_0x_0 + \frac a2x_0^2 - s = 0$$
where $a = (y_1-y_0)/(x_1-x_0)$.

When I try to solve it with some test values, I'm getting a negative determinant, which indicates that my equation is incorrect. Where is the error?

I derived my equation from:
$$s = (x_2-x_0)(y_2+y_0)/2$$
and
$$y_2 = y_0 + a(x_2-x_0)$$

by substituting $y_2$ in the first one.

**EDIT**

The test values I'm using are: $(x_0, y_0) = (1, 1);  (x_1, y_1) = (2, 0.1);  s = 0.4$, which result in $-0.45x_2^2 + 1.9x_2 - 2.05 = 0$ equation with $-0.08$ determinant.

Comment: It would be easier for others to spot the error if you show how you derived your equation.

Comment: @Travis I edited my question with more detail, thanks.

Comment: Seems to me that your reasoning and calculus is correct. Can you show which test values you took?

Comment: @Martigan I added the test values.

Comment: It seems to me that your third term is wrong: I have $-1.85$ and not $-2.05$...

Comment: @Martigan You are correct. I was looking at values while debugging my code and I omitted a pair of braces, which changed the equation. I should have calculated it manually instead. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: A typo corrected and explanatory picture added for trapezium formula after 3 years!

Answer (score 1):

Direct integration of area under straight line

$$ y = y_0  + a ( x -x_0) ; \; a = \frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} $$

$$ s = (x_2-x_0) \cdot ( y_0+ \frac {a}{2} (x_2-x_0)) \tag1$$

Imagine average height mid-way between AD and BC. The Trapezium Formula is

$$ Base\cdot Average Height$$

$$ s = AB \cdot \frac{(AD+BC)}{2}\tag2 $$

where each term corresponds with 1).

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the line equation be offset, to give $y = y_0 + a (x - x_0)$?